# I am not getting the paypal transaction variables to return correctly?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have integrated paypal standard website payment into my site. Once payment succeeds, I get the following variables from paypal:

```
tx=15J17947L4536803N&st=Pending&amt=119%2e99&cc=USD&cm=feature%5fitem%5fid%3d1%26deal%5fitem%5fname%3d0%26name%3dasd%2badfas%26email%3dasdfaddds%2540qwerqwe%2ecom%26cardholder%5fname%3d%26cvv%3d&item_number=
```

Why am I not getting any `txn_id` or any other status?  Also should I write code in my "payment was successful" page or in the `notify_url` of paypal_ipn?

Answer (score 1):

What you got in there is PDT (Payment Data Transfer) returned values, and `tx=15J17947L4536803N` is the transaction ID, corresponding to the `txn_id` field in IPN.

The difference between the two is that PDT works for displaying the transaction status to the customers, when they complete the payment and return to your "success page". While IPN is an async POST message sent to your 'notify_url', your listener script will capture & verify the message, then proceed with your order management/database operations

You may integrate both at the same time, just keep in mind that the variables and verification process is different between them

References:

[IPN & PDT Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EAB0105Z)

[PDT Sample Codes](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples)

[IPN Sample Codes](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

Comment: can i call only ipn script or is it necessary i should add ipn and pdt method both in paypal

Comment: if i use paypal ipn should i give notify url in paypal account settings. is it a must?

Comment: Enable IPN in your account is a must, while the `notify_url` in your code will override the IPN url you set in your account. That gives you flexibility to manage orders from multiple sites.

Comment: As what I said, PDT is for "displaying" transaction details to your customer,  it's optional as it could be easily aborted by user browser behaviors (like closing the browser before returning to your site)

Comment: when notify url returns i have  check session in construct itself so paypal cant return to my site how to handle this